# use jsoup cookies for HtmlUnit

Tags: java, cookies, jsoup, htmlunit

Can we use cookies extracted with JSOUP "Connection.Response" in HtmlUnit "WebClient"? I want to use jsoup for automated login in 'data.com', get the cookies from it and then parse a 'search result page' in 'data.com'  with HtmlUnit with java programming. A solution completely based on htmlUnit is also appreciated.

Comment: Why not doing both steps with HtmlUnit?

Comment: Yeah that also is good

Comment: There is nothing special to do because HtmlUnit handles cookies like your browser and will transfer it to the next request if needed (and as long as you do not close the WebClient.